# Facebook Open Graph Story Custom Actions Keep Getting Rejected - Advice Please?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Right, I know this is a question that has been asked over and over and over, but I have been researching, and reading Open Graph docs, and I am at a loss now.

This is the 3rd time my app has been rejected, sigh. Here's the low down:

We have a site that has an optional quizz that the user can take, should they wish to. It's fun and quirky, and arrives at a personality type as the end result.

As part of a competition element for a certain campaign, the user can share this story and stand a chance to win.

My custom object is "quiz" and my custom action is "complete".

In development, my app posts with the end result being "Simon took a quizz on somesite.com"

Facebook have rejected only the action "complete" with the following reason:

```
Your app should only publish actions taken within your app. Do not use verb actions that indicate content which the user looks at, browses, views, or discovers.
```

I am at my whits end! The quiz IS an action the user took within the app, they specifically opted in for it, and took it. If this scenario counts as content that the user discovered by browsing (which they did, BUT with specific actions that they TOOK on the app to get the resulting content) then what solution(s) do I have?

If I am not allowed verbs to indicate this content, what is the next best case? The story points to custom objects hosted on our server, which generate the users name, image and caption dynamically.

I sincerely hope I do not have to revert to a common "Simon likes a quizz somesite.com"

Any assistance is appreciate, as my deadline is now SUPER tight due to 3x failures.

NOTE: My previous action was "is", like "Simon is ax xxx type of a person" but that was rejected first because of tense, and again because of the same scenario above.

Thank you.

**EDIT #1:**

I have since changed the action from "is" to "complete" and it is being action on the object "quiz". The end story is "Simon completed a quiz". Here are the steps involved in my process:

1. Navigate to http://hellowekeend.capetown/dev/
2. Opt in to the quiz to find out what kind of a weekend person you are
3. Choose to share your result on Facebook by clicking "share your result on Facebook"
4. Authorize the app (if you're a Facebook review team member)
5. The app will open the share dialogue
6. Add extra text, set privacy etc and post to your timeline

**Facebook app ID is:** 862849823753236

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Step 1]
[image: User completes quiz]
[image: Quiz result]
[image: User opts in to share on Facebook]
[image: End result on Facebook]

**Some notes:**

The app DOES NOT post for you, therefore does not require the publish_actions permission.
The app uses a self branded button as that was the feedback, we were told NOT to use a Facebook branded button, which I am STILL convinced goes against the branding guidelines (??)

Comment: It seems that this was an error by the reviewing team. I checked this, and your app should have been approved. Can you provide your App ID? After that, you can submit again for review and I will make sure that this issue is resolved.

Comment: @Flaxfield - Thank you SO much for your response, my word you are the only one out of about 10,000 who made the effort to reach out, goodness me, THANK YOU! Are you referring to the fact that I must re submit using the action"is"? We have since switched to the action "complete" with the object "quiz" in the hope that we can get approved. That being said, do you see a problem with the end result being "Simon is a ABC kind of a weekend person"? I am going to update my question with screenshots of the entire process, along with my App ID. You're a life saver.

Comment: @Flaxfield - I have updated my question with what I hope is enough info to make sense of it. Sadly, because of 3 rejections I do not even have the original reference using the "is" action on the "weekend_type" object, neither of which even exist in my app configuration anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info! I've forwarded this to one of our reviewing-team. They will take special care of your submission. I actually think that both "is" and "completed" are good; it's up to you what you prefer. So please submit again with all the information you provided here and they will get to it!

Comment: Thank you @Flaxfield I am going to submit the review request in the next 20mins.

Comment: Your submission is now approved :) All the best with your app, looks like nice quizes!

Comment: The biggest problems at the Facebook review process are: 1. There's no direct way of communication with the review team. 2. Being forced to create screenshots in order to be able to give clear instructions is making the whole process awfully cumbersome.

Comment: @user324820 - Could you imagine the amount of ridiculous support requests they would have to deal with if there was direct access to support personal? I agree that there should be some level of contact if you reach a certain point, or at least if they can SEE by your submissions that you cant action their feedback. As for screenshots, that's very necessary! Imagine the guy on the other end can not speak english (for whatever reason)? Let's be honest, screen shotting takes 2mins

Comment: @SimonDowdles - A flood of ridiculous support requests would make Facebook at least aware if there's something wrong. Sure, screenshots are important, they are just unsuitable to replace written communication. Neither can you edit them afterwards, nor do you have any history of the past communication. All in all, the review process is surprisingly cumbersome and even something like an old school bulletin board would deliver a better service.

Comment: @user324820 - I agree, I think of all the elements of the API, the review process is the most daunting process, largely due to the fact that there seem to be large inconsistencies between personal, and I often feel it sometimes boils down to personal opinion of your app by the reviewer at the time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: this was originally a comment, but since it indicated the issue I'm making an Answer of it)

It seems that this was an error by the reviewing team. I checked this, and your app should have been approved. Can you provide your App ID? After that, you can submit again for review and I will make sure that this issue is resolved.

Comment: You, my friend, deserve a medal! Thank you so much. If I am ever in your area (I'm only on the other end of the world) I owe you a beer. All the best mate.

Comment: Ha, thank you so much :) I'm happy to have been of help! My colleague who handled your submission also says hi :)