# Facebook Open Graph Story is rejected, need advice on a fix to get approved, please?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We have an issue with approving the open graph stories for our game, which is very similar to this question: [Facebook Open Graph Story Custom Actions Keep Getting Rejected - Advice Please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112249/facebook-open-graph-story-custom-actions-keep-getting-rejected-advice-please/30210754#30210754)

The actions I was sending to Facebook for approval were: "Beat a friend",  "Gain an Achievement", "Help a Friend", "Send a Life", "Send Moves",  "Send Time" -  as you can see, all these actions  are regular actions of the player in a king-like game, but we've got a rejection for all of them with the same reason "Your app should only publish actions taken within your app. Do not use verb actions that indicate content which the user looks at, browses, views, or discovers."

Can anyone, please, give us a tip on how we need to edit the stories to get approvals? I don't see why these could be rejected - all these are actions player takes in the game, and to me they do sound like actions...

Comment: Welcome to the club! I'm suffering the same problem...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be regarding Facebook customer support.

Comment: Three upvotes in less than 24 hours - people actually need an answer to this. There is no support from Facebook and if it doesn't get answered here, where else can we go? So please don't close this as off-topic!

Comment: @user324820 although this question could be of interest to Stack Overflow users, that does not change whether it is on topic for SO. This is a support question for facebook, not a programming question, and therefore doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 0):

ok, we resolved this by just adding comments on what are player's actions leading to publishing this or that story directly on the screenshots that we've submitted to Facebook.
I hope this little advice will help someone else as well